# If condition with NOT operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
   for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
   {
        if (words[i].match(' '))
            words2[words2.length] = words[i];
    }
```

I want my if statement to be executed like this:

```
     if !(words[i].match(' '))
        words2[words2.length] = words[i];
```

How can I make the following statement **if not**, instead of regular if?

Comment: if (!words[i].match(' '))

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: words2.push(words[i]);  but you need to define it first **var words2 = [];**

Comment: JavaScript (like Java, C#, and various other languages) doesn't have an "if not" statement, it has "if (some condition)". If you want the effect of "if not" you have to negate your condition using the `! ` operator as *part of the condition* (that is, put it inside the if's parentheses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the complete answer:

```
var words2 = [];

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
{
    if (!words[i].match(' '))
        words2.push(words[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Please upvote my question as it was definitely not a silly question. The javascript does not behave the way you expect..

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (!words[i].match(' '))
     words2[words2.length] = words[i];
```

Comment: I was doing exactly the same thing, my node.js wont compile it.

Comment: Are you sure words2 is an array?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put the `!` *inside* the `if ()` statement's condition, so `if (!words[i].match(' '))`. Also, just like your `for` loop, you should enclose the instructions inside `{}`. So, should be:

`if (!words[i].match(' ')) {
     words2[words2.length] = words[i];
}`

Comment: @HarisGhauri what are you trying to do, exactly? You want to get all the values that aren't " "?